# How to use Manual Routing inside Vuex actions?

Tags: nativescript-vue

I am trying to use $navigateTo function inside **Vuex actions**

- `_this.$navigateTo` is not a function.
- `Vue.prototype.$navigateTo(Test)` is also pointless since you can't navigate between components.
- `$navigateTo` does not exist in `Vuex.Store`

## How to navigate with Vuex actions nativescipt-vue?

```ts
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import Test from "./components/Test.vue";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  actions: {
    go() {
      this.$navigateTo(Test); 
//Property '$navigateTo' does not exist on type 'Store<unknown>'.
    }
  }
});
```

Please check out my repo
It navigates to test page even it has an empty password

https://github.com/kaanguru/vuexnavigate

https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/manual-routing/#navigatetocomponent-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `Vue.prototype.$navigateTo(Test)` was the correct answer

```
Vue.prototype.$navigateTo(Test) is also pointless since you can't navigate between components.
```

No, it's not pointless you can navigate between components.